# Non-reactive sort with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a list of comments in my page which the user can upvote.

I want these comments to be sorted by the number of upvotes.

However, since the Comments collection is reactive, once a user upvotes a comment, the order of the comments changes reactively, which I don't like because it's very confusing for the user (the comment goes on top and it seems like it disappeared).

I still want the comments to be somewhat reactive (when someone adds a new comment or updates it, it should appear on the page without refreshing).
I don't mind if the user has to refresh the page to see the comments sorted by upvotes.
How do I make the order by number of upvotes non-reactive?

This is the template:

```
{{#each comments}}
  {{>comment}}
{{/each}}
```

and the helper:

```
Template.post.helpers({
  comments: function() {
    return Comments.find({},{sort: {numberOfUpvotes: -1});
  }
}
```

I thought about using `Tracker.nonreactive()`, but I'm not really sure how this would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you subscribe to that collection? The way I would subscribe in that situation is:

```
return Comments.find({}, {sort: {numberOfUpvotes: -1}, reactive: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective, the answer is easy: animations! When they upvote, they SEE the post move up the chain. I think discover meteor has this exact example in the last chapter of the book, so just give it a read & it'll walk you through how to use uihooks (or just check out their github).

Disabling reactivity until a refresh, although possible, is kind of ugly. If you wanted to do that, just do a `Comments.find({postId: 'foo'},{reactive:false});` in your helper.

Comment: I might take a look at animations, thanks for the tip.